# powershell send email with dynamic foldercontent

Tags: powershell

i have a script, that unzips files and then renames the folders to the name of the unzipped pdf inside.
I want to add that the script sends the content of each unzipped folder as an email

```
$SourceDir = 'C:\Install\NB\Teststart'
$ExtractDir = 'C:\Install\NB\Testfinal'

# Extract each zip to a folder with the same name as the zip file (BaseName)
Get-ChildItem (Join-Path $SourceDir *.zip) | foreach {
    Expand-Archive $_.FullName -DestinationPath (Join-Path $ExtractDir $_.BaseName)
}

# Rename the PDF's parent folder to the same as the PDF
Get-ChildItem (Join-Path $ExtractDir *.pdf) -Recurse | foreach {
    Rename-Item -Path $_.Directory.FullName -NewName $_.BaseName
}
```

the foldernames are partly-generated & static names and change from zipfile to zipfile.

Comment: Take a look at `Send-MailMessage` [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-6]

Comment: yeah i already did that, and have the send command working, but i don't know how to address the "randomly" named folders. the folders have names like:
- asdawd-ersrfse-231-Formular,  
- asdawd-esgdghre-34578-Formular,  
- lkjklj-werhdtr-567-Formular

Comment: Include your code for the Send-MailMessage so we can see what you've got, you can hide server/domain/email with `domain.com` and `user@domain.com` etc.

Comment: Are you wanting to send one email with everything, or one email per folder?

Comment: i'm too stupid to format it correct in the comment: $PSEmailServer = "mail..."  
Send-MailMessage -From 'Sender>' -To 'receiver' -Subject 'Formular Antrag' -Body 'new Form available' -DeliveryNotificationOption OnSuccess, OnFailure -Attachments $ExtractDir...

Comment: i want to send one email for each folder. So in each email will be one pdf and the other 4 xmls files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is `-Attachments $ExtractDir` - you are trying to attach a string `'C:\Install\NB\Testfinal'` to your email.

You need to get the files that are inside the folder and attach them.

Again `Get-ChildItem` can be used for this, by now you can see a theme when working with files ;)

```
foreach ($folder in (Get-ChildItem $ExtractDir -Directory)) { # loop through each folder
    $files = Get-ChildItem (Join-Path $ExtractDir $folder) -File  | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName # get files in that folder and assign to variable
    Send-MailMessage [your other params] -Attachments $files # use variable as your attachments
}
```

Comment: it is not working, it seams like it is messig up with the folder inside $ExtractDir:
`Send-MailMessage : The File 
"C:\Install\NB-Skript\0c147bc4-544c-64030381c3fa_Formular.pdf" could not be found.` but it is missing the folder where the file is inside, its not inside NB-Skript, it is inside the subfolder of NB-Skript

Comment: Try updating `$files = Get-ChildItem (Join-Path $ExtractDir $folder) -File | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName`